# how to have multiply constructors in one class?

Tags: java, class, constructor

I want to have two constructors in one class but I can't. I know it is possible but I can't find my mistake.

```
     public static class Matrix{
        int [][] matrix;
        int row;
        int column;
        String matrixName;
        Matrix (String [] input, String name) {
            matrixName = name;
            column = input.length;
            row = input[0].split(",").length;
            matrix = new int [row][column];
            initialize(input);
        }

        Matrix (Matrix A, char ch) {
            if (ch == 'T'){
                column = A.row;
                row = A.column;
            }
            else{
                column = A.column;
                row = A.row;
            }
            matrix = new int[row][column];
            matrixName = "result";
        }
```

the second **Matrix** can't be defined as a constructor.

Comment: what is an error you're getting?

Comment: @AbhiN in another class I have `Matrix result = new Matrix (Matrix A, 'R');` and I get this error  Error:(121, 47) java: ')' expected
Error:(121, 48) java: not a statement
Error:(121, 49) java: ';' expected

Comment: Write just  `A` for the first parameter in the `new` call, not `Matix A`.

Comment: i don't think you can pass Matrix as an argument , because if it was allowed then  for the initialization of that Matrix A object the second constructor will need to be executed it you make it with second constructor and in that execution too the second costructor need to execute again , and this way you will stuck in infinite loop.

Comment: Downvoted because you did not share the error message. See [mcve], thanks.

Comment: @AbhiN Thank you, It was an embarrassing mistake :/

Comment: so did you understand my comment, i thought i was not explaining in detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem with the second constructor. The problem is with the first line of the declaration which is `public static class Matrix`. Note that you can not use `static` modifier here. Only `public`, `abstract` and `final` are allowed.

After this correction, you can test your class as follows:

```
class Matrix {
    int[][] matrix;
    int row;
    int column;
    String matrixName;

    Matrix(String[] input, String name) {
        matrixName = name;
        column = input.length;
        row = input[0].split(",").length;
        matrix = new int[row][column];
        // initialize(input);
        System.out.println("First");
    }

    Matrix(Matrix A, char ch) {
        if (ch == 'T') {
            column = A.row;
            row = A.column;
        } else {
            column = A.column;
            row = A.row;
        }
        matrix = new int[row][column];
        matrixName = "result";
        System.out.println("Second");
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Matrix m1 = new Matrix(new String[] { "a", "b" }, "Hello");
        Matrix m2 = new Matrix(m1, 'X');
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
First
Second
```

Comment: Mr arvind do you think my comment on OP post make sense, i was just an idea, can you tell

Comment: @AbhinavChauhan - No, your understanding is not correct. Check the sample output.

Comment: can you check by doing Matrix m2 = new Matrix(m2,'x');, i am not sure about my hypothesis

Comment: @AbhinavChauhan - Your proposal, `can you check by doing Matrix m2 = new Matrix(m2,'x'); ` is syntactically wrong. It will fail with a compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

Is it nested class in another class? Because class can be static only when it is nested in another class like this:

```
public class Matrix {

    public static class NestedClass {

        int number;
        String string;

        public NestedClass(NestedClass A, String string) {
            this.number = A.number;
            this.string = string;
        }

        public NestedClass(NestedClass A) {
            this.string = A.string;
        }
    }
}
```

Class Matrix cannot be static, only final or abstract.